# Filtering a pandas dataframe properly

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

I am trying to filter a pandas dataframe using a function and am running into SettingWithCopyWarning warning. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. Below is a general outline of my code:

```
def cleanData(data):
    out = data.query("data.x < 100")
    out.z = out.z == "Z"
    return out
data = cleanData(data)
```

I would like to be able to keep it in this function form, as I want to run the function on both my train and test data. Thanks :)

Comment: Change the out variable to data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.copy()`:

```
def cleanData(data):
    out = data.query("data.x < 100").copy()
    out.z = out.z == "Z"
    return out
data = cleanData(data)
```

Comment: Thank you! such an obvious solution haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
out = data.query("data.x < 100").copy()
```

If you modify values in `out` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`data`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. I want to set data.z to be equal to data.z == 'Z'. So it would become a boolean. Further, this is being done on many other columns of the frame.

Comment: Gotcha, I understand the reason for the warning better now. As I am setting it to the return it should still work in the original format, but the .copy() does get rid of the warning. Thank you!